# jest test case for input change and button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, sinon

I am very new to jest so i don't know how to proceed with jest. I have write test case using jest for input on change and button click for the below component. But it failed. issue with  'Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.' please help me

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

class FITB extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.String = String;
    this.defaultTextSize = 8;
    this.state = {
      inputList: [],
      splitList: [],
      count: 0,
      isValid: false
    };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSend = this.onClickSend.bind(this);
    this.checkInputValidations = this.checkInputValidations.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  onInputChange(index) {
    return (event) => {
      const inputList = this.state.inputList;
      let isValid = true;
      inputList[index] = event.target.value;
      if (!this.isValidInput(inputList[index])) {
        isValid = false;
      }
      this.setState({
        inputList,
        isValid
      });
      // console.log('onInputChange fib state', this.state);
    };
  }

  onClickSend() {
    const {
      splitList,
      inputList,
      count
    } = this.state;
    // console.log('onClickSend fib before state', this.state);
    const onReply = this.props.onReply;
    let fullText = '';
    splitList.map((text, index) => {
      fullText += text;
      if ((index < count - 1) && inputList[index]) {
        fullText += inputList[index];
      }
      return true;
    });

    if (onReply) {
      onReply(fullText);
    }
    // console.log('onClickSend fib after state', this.state);
  }

  isValidInput(text) {
    const regex = /^[\u0020-\u007e]*$/;
    const replaceChar160RegExp = new RegExp(this.String.fromCharCode(160), 'g');
    return regex.test(text.replace(replaceChar160RegExp, ' '));
  }

  initialize() {
    let text = '';
    this.props.messages.map((element) => {
      if (element.type && (typeof element.type === 'string') && (element.type === 'FILL_IN_THE_BLANK')) {
        text = element.message;
      }
      // console.log('inside fib', text);
      return text;
    });
    const splitList = text.split(/_+/g);
    this.setState({
      splitList,
      count: splitList.length
    });
    // console.log('init fib state', this.state);
  }

  checkInputValidations() {
    const {
      inputList,
      count,
      isValid
    } = this.state;
    let i;
    let flag = false;
    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i += 1) {
      if (!inputList[i] || inputList[i].trim() === '') {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    // console.log('checkInputValidations', this.state);
    return flag || !isValid;
  }

  render() {
    const {
      splitList,
      count,
      inputList
    } = this.state;
    // console.log('reder fitb', this.state);
    return (
      <Col lg={12} className="rply-block">
        <Col lg={11} className="textarea-block">
          <div className="fitb-wrap">
            { splitList && splitList.map((item, index) => (
              <span>
                <span className="fitb-text">{item}</span>
                { (index < count - 1) && (
                  <input
                    className="fitb-input"
                    type="text"
                    maxLength="40"
                    size={(inputList[index] && inputList[index].length > this.defaultTextSize && inputList[index].length) || this.defaultTextSize}
                    value={inputList[index]}
                    onChange={this.onInputChange(index)}
                    autoFocus={index === 0}
                    aria-describedby={count > 1 ? `Missing word ${index + 1} of ${count - 1}` : 'Missing word'}
                    aria-label="Fill in missing words"
                  />
                )}
              </span>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={1} className="">
          <button
            className="btn-info-dm"
            role="button"
            tabIndex="0"
            onClick={this.onClickSend}
            disabled={this.checkInputValidations()}
          >Send</button>
        </Col>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

FITB.propTypes = {
  onReply: React.PropTypes.isRequired,
  messages: React.PropTypes.array
};

export default FITB;
```

test files for the input and button click

```
import React from 'react';
import FITB from '../components/dialogManager/fitb';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('FITB', () => {
  let component;
  const mockFn = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<FITB onReply={mockFn} />);
  });
  test('Should initialize the FITB content', () => {
    expect(component.find('.rply-block')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  test('Should have been called send', () => {
    component.find('.btn-info-dm').simulate('click');
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  test('Should render the text box', () => {
    expect(component.state().inputList).toEqual([]);
    expect(component.state().isValid).toEqual(false);
    // expect(component.find('input.fitb-input')).toBeDefined();
    console.log('state== ', component.state());
    console.log('input == ', component.find('.fitb-input'));
    component.find('.fitb-input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Qualitative data includes detailed interviews, direct _____, and historical records.' } });
    console.log('fitb-input onchange== ', component.find('.fitb-input'));
    expect(component.state().inputList).toEqual('Qualitative data includes detailed interviews, direct _____, and historical records.');
    expect(component.state().isValid).toEqual(true);
  });
  // test('Should check the input label', () => {
  //   const expectedFitbTextLabel = 'Fill in missing words';
  //   const fitbTextList = [];
  //   console.log('span fitb txt== ', component.find('.fitb-text').instance().label);
  //   component.find('.fitb-text').map((elem) => {
  //     fitbTextList.push(elem.text().trim());
  //   });
  //   expect(component.find('.fitb-text').instance().label).toEqual(expectedFitbTextLabel);
  // });
  test('Should render the fitbText ', () => {
    const expectedFitbText = 'Qualitative data includes detailed interviews, direct _____, and historical records.';
    const fitbTextList = [];
    console.log('span fitb txt== ', component.find('.fitb-text').text());
    // fitbTextList.push(expectedFitbText.split(/_+/g));
    // console.log('fitbTextList= ', fitbTextList);
    component.find('.fitb-text').map((elem) => {
      fitbTextList.push(elem.text().trim());
    });
    expect(fitbTextList).toEqual(expectedFitbText);
  });
  test('Should check the fitbText ', () => {
    const expectedFitbText = 'Qualitative data includes detailed interviews, direct _____, and historical records.';
    const fitbTextList = [];
    fitbTextList.push(expectedFitbText.split(/_+/g));
    expect(component.state().inputList).toEqual([]);
    console.log('input list init== ', component.state().inputList);
    component.find('input.fitb-input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } });
    console.log('input list== ', component.state().inputList);
    // component.find('input').instance().onInputChange(0);
    // expect(component.state().inputList).toEqual('test');
  });
});
```

for the another component on button click to send the details

```
import React from 'react';

class ReplyButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.replyBtnWrap = '';
    this.replyBtnList = '';
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      isLeftArrowEnabled: false,
      isRightArrowEnabled: false
    };

    this.onClickLeftArrow = this.onClickLeftArrow.bind(this);
    this.onClickRightArrow = this.onClickRightArrow.bind(this);
    this.onClickReplyBtn = this.onClickReplyBtn.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initializeList();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkElementOffset();
  }

  onClickRightArrow() {
    const wrapElement = this.replyBtnWrap;
    const listElement = this.replyBtnList;
    const wrapWidth = wrapElement.offsetWidth;
    const listWidth = listElement.offsetWidth;
    let listLeft = wrapElement.scrollLeft;
    let listOverflowWidth = 0;
    listLeft += 400;
    listOverflowWidth = listWidth - listLeft;
    if (listOverflowWidth < 0) {
      listLeft = listWidth - wrapWidth;
    }
    wrapElement.scrollLeft = listLeft;
    this.checkElementOffset();
  }

  onClickLeftArrow() {
    const wrapElement = this.replyBtnWrap;
    let listLeft = wrapElement.scrollLeft;

    listLeft -= 400;

    if (listLeft < 0) {
      listLeft = 0;
    }
    wrapElement.scrollLeft = listLeft;
    this.checkElementOffset();
  }

  onClickReplyBtn(item) {
    return () => {
      const onReply = this.props.onReply;
      if (onReply) {
        onReply(item);
      }
    };
  }

  checkElementOffset() {
    const wrapElement = this.replyBtnWrap;
    const listElement = this.replyBtnList;
    const wrapWidth = wrapElement.offsetWidth;
    const listWidth = listElement.offsetWidth;
    const listLeft = wrapElement.scrollLeft;
    let listOverflowWidth = 0;
    let isLeftArrowEnabled = false;
    let isRightArrowEnabled = false;
    if (listLeft > 0) {
      isLeftArrowEnabled = true;
    }
    listOverflowWidth = listWidth - listLeft - wrapWidth;
    if (listOverflowWidth > 0) {
      isRightArrowEnabled = true;
    }
    if (this.state.isLeftArrowEnabled !== isLeftArrowEnabled || this.state.isRightArrowEnabled !== isRightArrowEnabled) {
      this.setState({
        isLeftArrowEnabled,
        isRightArrowEnabled
      });
    }
  }

  initializeList() {
    // this.setState({
    //   list: [{
    //     type: 'MENU_ITEM',
    //     text: 'what is quantitative research?',
    //     return_value: 'what is quantitative research?'
    //   }, {
    //     type: 'MENU_ITEM',
    //     text: 'what is mixed method research?',
    //     return_value: 'what is mixed method research?'
    //   }, {
    //     type: 'MENU_ITEM',
    //     text: 'what is qualitative research?',
    //     return_value: 'what is qualitative research?'
    //   }, {
    //     type: 'MENU_ITEM',
    //     text: 'I had a different question',
    //     return_value: 'I had a different question'
    //   }, {
    //     type: 'MENU_ITEM',
    //     text: 'That was actually my answer',
    //     return_value: 'That was actually my answer'
    //   }]
    // });
    const replyButtonText = [];
    // console.log('reply btns props = ', this.props);
    if (this.props.messages) {
      this.props.messages.map((element) => {
        if (element.type && (typeof element.type === 'string') && (element.type === 'MENU_ITEM')) {
          replyButtonText.push(element);
        }
        return this.setState({ list: replyButtonText });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const btnList = this.state.list;
    const {
      isLeftArrowEnabled,
      isRightArrowEnabled
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="r-wrap">
        { isLeftArrowEnabled && (
          <button className="r-btn-left-arrow" onClick={this.onClickLeftArrow} role="button" tabIndex="0">
            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" />
          </button>
        )}
        <div className="r-btn-wrap" ref={(e) => { this.replyBtnWrap = e; }}>
          <div className="r-btn-list" ref={(e) => { this.replyBtnList = e; }}>
            {
              btnList && btnList.map(btnItem => <button
                className="r-btn"
                role="button"
                tabIndex="0"
                onClick={this.onClickReplyBtn(btnItem)}
                title={btnItem.text}
              >{btnItem.text}</button>)
            }
          </div>
        </div>
        { isRightArrowEnabled && (
          <button className="r-btn-right-arrow" onClick={this.onClickRightArrow} role="button" tabIndex="0">
            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" />
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReplyButtons.propTypes = {
  onReply: React.PropTypes.isRequired,
  messages: React.PropTypes.array
};

export default ReplyButtons;
```

test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReplyButtons from '../components/dialogManager/replybuttons';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const mockOutputObj = [{
  type: 'MENU_ITEM',
  text: 'what is quantitative research?',
  return_value: 'what is quantitative research?'
}, {
  type: 'MENU_ITEM',
  text: 'what is mixed method research?',
  return_value: 'what is mixed method research?'
}];

describe('ReplyButtons', () => {
  let component;
  const mockFn = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<ReplyButtons onReply={mockFn} />);
  });

  test('Should initialize the ReplyButtons content', () => {
    expect(component.find('.r-wrap')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  test('Should check the ReplyButtons click', () => {
    console.log('r-btn==> ', component.find('button.r-btn'));
    component.find('.r-btn').simulate('click');
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: please attach the error log. this will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error happens because the selector in the last test case

```
component.find('button.r-btn')
```

refers to buttons that are build by iterating on this.state.list in the ReplyButtons component

AND you do not provide the prop 'messages' that would trigger a feeding to the list

try instanciating ReplyButtons with some messages like

```
beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<ReplyButtons onReply={mockFn} messages={['1','2']}/>);
});
```

and it should be ok (btw not having the error stack is pretty unconfortable here, there might be other issues)